# python exception message formatting

Tags: python, exception

**Question:**
Why don't I get an exception message when formatting the message with `%s` but I do with `format`?

Fails:

```
>>> Exception('foo %s', 'bar').message
''
```

Works:

```
>>> Exception('foo {}'.format('bar')).message
'foo bar'
```

Any explanation why it fails on `%s`?

Comment: BTW: the `message` attribute is deprecated and newer versions of python don't have it. Use just `str(Exception(...))` to get the message. Also it does not even seem to be documented in python2, contrary to `args`.  I believe `message` is set *only* if you provide a single argument to the constructor, otherwise it means that the exception contains other data inside `args` and the base implementation doesn't assume that you want to format everything into the message...

Comment: @Bakuriu I noticed this too, my hacky workaround was to do this: `>>> asdf = Exception('foo %s' % 'bar')` followed by `>>> asdf.message` which works (in Python 2.7). This has been removed completely in Python3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your syntax for the %-substitution in `Exception` is incorrect. You need to use `%` to specify the replacement string:

```
>>> Exception('foo %s' % 'bar').message
'foo bar'
```